# c# query database help

Tags: c#, sql

Im doing an OCR here. In my system, user inputs image, character and description.

if the user wants to input another image with same character and description, the user only needs to import the existing one to tell the system that the character and description are the same, so that they do not need to re-enter the character and description again.

Anyone knows how it can be done?

Here is my code :

```
con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SHEN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CharacterImage;Integrated Security=True";
            con.Open();

        //set variables to the textbox.text
        String ImageLocation = imgLoc.Text;
        String typeName = CharTB.Text;
        String ImportExt = importTB.Text;
        String CharDesc = DescTB.Text;
        String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ImageLocation);
        String savePath = @"C:\Users\Shen\Desktop\LenzOCR\LenzOCR\WindowsFormsApplication1\ImageFile\" + fileName;

        inputImageBox.Image = Image.FromFile(ImageLocation);
        inputImageBox.Image.Save(savePath);

        String insertData = "INSERT INTO CharacterImage(ImageName, ImagePath, Character, CharacterDescription) VALUES('"+fileName+"', '"+savePath+"', '"+typeName+"', '"+CharDesc+"')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertData, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Character Inserted", "Insert Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        descDisplayTB.Text = typeName + "\r\n\r\n" + CharDesc;
        //set the Textbox to empty and the "Type Character" textboxt to uneditable 
        //and the "Import" button to unclickable after user add the data into the database
        imgLoc.Text = "";
        CharTB.Text = "";
        importTB.Text = "";
        DescTB.Text = "";
        CharTB.ReadOnly = true;
        ImportButton.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        descDisplayTB.Text = "";
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be following steps work:

1. Ask user to enter Image id[may be browse or something else] of which details is going to be copied.
2. Fetch details for that image from database.
3. Insert newly updated image with the fetched details in database.

Comment: can u explain further on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be clearing the character and description fields after the first image is entered.  That way the user just needs to pick the next image, and re-submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I've a high level answer for you.

I would keep a collection of recently recognized or loaded data. 
Then as each item is loaded, you could create a scrolling window to select images of characters that were recently uploaded to the database, so the person does not need to re-associate it with your training set.